# How to handle two ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Hello i have sequence like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ctl00_txtsearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            // Here is the code of autocomplete which is requesting 
            // data and binding as autocomplete
            });
        });
 });
        var aa=bindonload();
    });
```

Here is the another function which i want to call on page load

```
function bindonload() { 
    $.get( "minicart.aspx#mydatacontent", function( data ) {
        var resourceContent = data;     
        var mini=$(resourceContent).find('div#pnlminicart');
        $('#smallcart').html(mini);
    });
    return false;
}
```

So , my actual problem is when page is loaded
first of all

> bindonload()

called and then autocomplete if textbox have some values right?
But when page is loaded and suddenly i started to write into autocomplete textbox then untill **bindlonload function gets executed** autocomplete will not work.

I don't have idea how to handle it i have used ***async:true*** but its not working i don't want to wait for second process

Thanks in advance....

Comment: var aa=bindonload(); this is for sure not correct. You can not have var inside method call.

Comment: I have @JernejNovak its working all right are you suggesting to do something else?

Comment: Oh sorry. Now looks OK.

Comment: How about if you block the input field until the request ends?

Comment: No request time is not fixed its can take 5-6 seconds and by the way i can not block it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well..what i guess..should be..you **loaddata()** should not be taking too much of time to load.

If there is any way to optimize , look of that.

If you ajax request has a dependency on the other, then you can not make it parallel

If you really intend to make parallel ajax requests, you have to make use of the following:

```
$.when($.ajax("URL1"), $.ajax("URL2"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Hope it helps..

**Note : The Ajax calls should not be dependent**

**Updated:**

```
    $.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 )
 { 

     // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.  
    // Each argument is an array with the following structure: 
    [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]  
    var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {    alert( "We got what we came for!" );  
}});
```

In the above example , you can see two ajax requests executes parallel

After the two requests are done, i.e on sucess of two functions , the add operation is being performed

Similarly , you can replace `$.ajax("/page1.php")` with your `loaddata()` and then

`$.ajax("page2.php")` with your `Auto Complete request`.

**Both of them will execute Parallely**

Comment: nice one but i already have used it i forget to add only its not working

Comment: can you give me one example?

Comment: i still not understand how i will implement this into my question